# Inno Setup: Show custom page before installation starts

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

How to display a custom wizard before starting one of the functions (Task - `printer`):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\First.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: First program install; Tasks: fp1;
Filename: "{tmp}\Second.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Second program install; Tasks: fp2;
Filename: "{tmp}\Drivers\Install.exe"; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Drivers install; Tasks: printer;
```

Code section:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  BitmapFileName: string;
  BitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
  WelcomePage: TWizardPage;
begin
  WelcomePage := CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling, '', '');    

  BitmapFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\image.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile(ExtractFileName(BitmapFileName));

  BitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WelcomePage);
  BitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
  BitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(BitmapFileName);
  BitmapImage.Cursor := crHand;
  BitmapImage.Left := 10;
  BitmapImage.Top := 10;
  BitmapImage.Parent := WelcomePage.Surface;
end;
```

I try to use as PageId `wpInstalling`, `wpInfoAfter`, and `wpFinished` but all of them are show after drivers install completed. And I need this window to appear after installing the second program, but before starting to install the driver.

Comment: I've posted a new answer. The previous one was completely wrong. For some reason I believed that the first argument of `CreateCustomPage` is "Before ID", while it is actually "After ID".

Answer (score 1):

The last page before installation is the *"Select Additional Tasks"*, so use `wpSelectTasks` for `AfterID` parameter of [`CreateCustomPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustompage):

```pascal
WelcomePage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks, '', '');
```

(it does not matter if the *"Select Additional Tasks"* actually displays or not)